# I want to selected only the 1st 11 children of my choice from a parent (div) with class name (my class), the rest I ignore them

Tags: xpath

I want an Xpath to select only

and  tags under the class "my class" and ignore other children

I've tried the following X-path but it not working
//div[@class="my class"]/p and ul/text()

```
<div class = "my class">
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <ul>...</ul>
   <p>...</p>
   <ul>...</ul>
   <a class="my child class" href="#">...</a>
   <div class="my second child class" href="#">...</div>
</div>
```

Expected to select all

an  tags under the class = "my class" the rest ignore

Comment: Your question is unclear; everything in your code is a child of the top `<div>`; what exactly is your desired output?

Comment: note that everything is a child of top <div> and its not a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your need correctly you want to select either the `p` element or `ul` element under your div.

**There is two ways to do this :**

Using `self::`

```
//div[@class="my class"]/*[self::p or self::ul]/text()
```

or using `local-name()`

```
//div[@class="my class"]/*[local-name()='p' or local-name()='ul']/text()
```

Comment: Thanks alot Nesku, I got your answer, I'm really happy with it but, infact I want to select both p element and  ul , not either of them as this one works for either of them. thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, this actually select both `p` or `ul`. What I mean by either is that this select the elements under your `div[@class="my class"]` than can be either `p` or `ul`.

Comment: Thanks Alot Nesku, I realy appreciate your time, for the last time, what if mayb also within <div> children, they are some <h2> tags and I also want to selected them along <ul> and <p>, should I . use something like ( //div[@class="my class"]/*[self::p or self::ul or self::h2]/text() ) ?

Comment: You're welcome, and yes if you also want to include `<h2>` tags you can do this.